# Twitter redirect using auth.BeginAuthorization on website but not in localhost

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I have implementing Twitter using LinqToTwitter.

Everything work fine on Localhost so I migrate that to my DEV environment.
Unfortunately on my DEV environment, when I click on the Twitter Login Button there is no redirection to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize and I have no error.

Is somebody has an explanation on that please?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I have to authorize this three urls?
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

Comment: I check and this is ok for these URL. Maybe it is because of the callback url specify in my "Application Details"? I put http://nom_de_mon_site.fr

Answer (score 1):

If you use yet, check your web.config add this:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/404.html">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/404.html" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this is happening for me. When I was authenticating a user, I used the following code:

```
IOAuthCredentials credentials = new SessionStateCredentials();
if (credentials.ConsumerKey == null || credentials.ConsumerSecret == null)
{
    credentials.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey;
    credentials.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;
}
auth = new WebAuthorizer
{
    Credentials = credentials,
    PerformRedirect = authUrl => HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(authUrl)
};
```

The problem is the `SessionStateCredentials()`. It works the first time, but if you resubmit it (during development & debugging for example) without first clearing the sessions (because it runs in SessionState), it won't redirect. My fix was to change this line:

`IOAuthCredentials credentials = new SessionStateCredentials();`

to this:

`IOAuthCredentials credentials = new InMemoryCredentials();`

After that, everything works now. I hope someone gets some help from this.